# How to send and resend back fxml object

Tags: java, javafx

I'd like to take Pane object from controller class to another class called Wykres in my case, then add to it children for example Circle's objects, but when I try to generate circles by clicking button there is no circles, can someone help me? Thanks.

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
public Label label_x_waga;

@FXML
Label label_y_waga;

@FXML
Pane root_pane;

@FXML
Button button_add;

private static Pane panee;
private SiecNeuronowa siecNeuronowa;

public void initialize(){

    siecNeuronowa = new SiecNeuronowa();
    panee=root_pane;

}

public static Pane getPane(){
    return panee;
}

@FXML
public void button_add_action(){
    root_pane = Wykres.getPane_root();

    for(int i=0;i<300;i++)
        siecNeuronowa.dodajPunkt();
}
```

}

And the Wykres class

```
public class Wykres {
private int xWartosc, yWartosc;
private String kolor;
private static Pane pane_root;

public void rysujPunkt(Pane root, int x, int y, String color){
    x+=180;
    y+=180;
    xWartosc = x;
    yWartosc = y;
    this.kolor = color;
    if(color.equals("NIEBIESKI")){
        root.getChildren().add(new Circle(x, y, 5, Color.BLUE));
    }
    else if(color.equals("CZERWONY")){
        root.getChildren().add(new Circle(x, y, 5, Color.RED));
    }

    pane_root = root;

}

public static Pane getPane_root(){return pane_root;}
```

}

rysujPunkt() method is invoked here:

```
public class SiecNeuronowa {
private Perceptron perceptron1;
private Wykres wykres1;

public SiecNeuronowa(){
    wykres1 = new Wykres();
    perceptron1 = new Perceptron(){

        @Override
        public double finalizuj_dane(double potencjalMembranowy){
            if(potencjalMembranowy>0)
                return 1;

            else
            if(potencjalMembranowy<0)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    };

    perceptron1.dodajWejscia(2);

    Random random = new Random();
    double rand_x = random.nextDouble();
    double rand_y = random.nextDouble();
    perceptron1.setWagaWejsciowa(0, rand_x);
    perceptron1.setWagaWejsciowa(1, rand_y);


}

public void dodajPunkt(){
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.nextInt()*150;
    int y = random.nextInt()*150;

    perceptron1.setDaneWejsciowe(0, x);
    perceptron1.setDaneWejsciowe(1, y);

    int wynik = (int)perceptron1.getWyjscie();

    if(wynik == 1)
        wykres1.rysujPunkt(Controller.getPane(), x, y, "Niebieski");
    else
        if(wynik == -1)
            wykres1.rysujPunkt(Controller.getPane(), x, y, "Czerwony");


}
```

}

Comment: Where is the `rysujPunkt` method invoked? The only occurance of that string in your post is the method declaration. Furthermore keeping a `static` reference to the pane seems weird to me. You should have a good reason to store a parameter passed to some method updating the object in a static field...

Comment: I've added invoke of rysujPunkt

Comment: You're not passing the strings you test for to the `rysujPunkt` method, even if `wynik` is 1 or -1: The ones you test for are all uppercase, for the ones you pass only the first letter is uppercase. I recommend using `boolean` or an enum instead of strings for this kind of information. This way these kind of typos yield compile time errors instead of resulting in bugs. Also you should change the way you pass around the pane. Using a static member is the least maintainable way of passing the info around. You could pass the pane using the `SiecNeuronowa` constructor or `dodajPunkt` method param